# Not able to use two UIPickerView in the same Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I'm trying to use more than two UIPickerViews together in one ViewController. Each UIPickerView has different data array. I am using interface builder to link the pickers up. What I want is, after button click, my PickerView will show up and user can select the data from it.That selected data will come in the text field. It is working fine for first PickerView but when I click for the second PickerView, the value is coming from first array and I am not able to write condition. Here's all my code:

**.h file**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface Tabbar2ViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>{

        IBOutlet UIPickerView *genderPickerView;
        IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerViewoption;

        IBOutlet UIButton *BrandPickerBtn;
        IBOutlet UIButton *genderPickerfBtn;

        NSArray *brands;
        NSArray *gender;
        BOOL isCheckedpickerView;


        IBOutlet UILabel *BrandLabelfield;
        IBOutlet UILabel *GenderLabelfield;

    }

    - (IBAction)action:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)genderAction:(id)sender;

    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *brands;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *gender;

    @end
```

**.m file**

```
#import "ttViewController.h"

@interface ttViewController ()

@end



 @implementation ttViewController
    @synthesize countries,size,brands,gender,activity,condition,color;

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        isCheckedpickerView=FALSE;
        pickerViewoption.hidden=YES;
        genderPickerView.hidden=YES;
        activityPickerView.hidden=YES;
        conditionPickerView.hidden=YES;
        sizeandquantityPickerView.hidden=YES;


        BrandLabelfield = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 812, 253, 35)];
        BrandLabelfield.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        BrandLabelfield.text=@"Brand";
        BrandLabelfield.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header_01.png"]];
         BrandLabelfield.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Open Sans" size:14];
        [tabView1 addSubview:BrandLabelfield];


        //GenderTextfield with Label //

        GenderLabelfield = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 865, 253, 35)];
        GenderLabelfield.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        GenderLabelfield.text=@"Gender";
        GenderLabelfield.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Open Sans" size:14];
        [tabView1 addSubview:GenderLabelfield];

        //ColorTextfield with Label //

        ConditionLabelfield = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 1113, 253, 35)];
        ConditionLabelfield.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        ConditionLabelfield.text=@"Color";
        ConditionLabelfield.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Open Sans" size:14];
        [tabView1 addSubview:ConditionLabelfield];
        brands=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Nike",@"Bata",@"Adidas", nil];
        gender=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Male",@"Female",@"Unisex", nil];
        activity=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"BASEBALL",@"BASKETBALL",@"FOOTBALL",@"GOLF",@"RUNNING",@"SKATING",@"SOCCER",@"SPORTS & OUTDOOR",@"TENNIS",@"TRAINING",@"VOLLEY BALL",@"WRESTLING", nil];

        // Custom PICKER VIEWS //


        pickerViewoption=[[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 852, 290, 41)];
        pickerViewoption.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        pickerViewoption.delegate = self;
        pickerViewoption.dataSource=self;
        pickerViewoption.hidden=YES;
        [pickerViewoption setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [tabView1 addSubview:pickerViewoption];

        genderPickerView=[[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 906, 290, 41)];
        genderPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        genderPickerView.delegate = self;
        genderPickerView.dataSource=self;
        genderPickerView.hidden=YES;
        [genderPickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [tabView1 addSubview:genderPickerView];

        activityPickerView=[[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 954, 290, 41)];
        activityPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        activityPickerView.delegate = self;
        activityPickerView.dataSource=self;
        activityPickerView.hidden=YES;
        [activityPickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [tabView1 addSubview:activityPickerView];




        pickerViewoption.tag=1;
        genderPickerView.tag=2;
        activityPickerView.tag=3;

        BrandPickerBtn.tag=000;
        genderPickerfBtn.tag=111;
        activityPickerBtn.tag=222;

     }


    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
        return 1;
         }


    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
    forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

        NSString *string;


        if (pickerViewoption.tag==1) {

             [tabView1 addSubview:pickerViewoption];
            string=[self.brands objectAtIndex:row];
        }
        else  {
                [tabView1 addSubview:genderPickerView];
                 string=[self.gender objectAtIndex:row];
              }


        else if (genderPickerView.tag==2){
            [tabView1 addSubview:genderPickerView];
            string=[self.gender objectAtIndex:row];
       }

        else if (activityPickerView.tag==3){
          [tabView1 addSubview:activityPickerView];
           string=[self.activity objectAtIndex:row];
       }




     return string;

          }


    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
           inComponent:(NSInteger)component {


        if (pickerViewoption.tag==1){
            BrandLabelfield.text=@"";
             BrandLabelfield.text=[brands objectAtIndex:row];
            BrandLabelfield.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            pickerViewoption.hidden=YES;

        }
        else if (genderPickerView.tag==2){
             GenderLabelfield.text=@"";
             GenderLabelfield.text=[gender objectAtIndex:row];
            GenderLabelfield.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];}

        else if (activityPickerView.tag==3){
            ActivityLabelfield.text=@"";
            ActivityLabelfield.text=[activity objectAtIndex:row];
            ActivityLabelfield.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    }

     }



    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{


        if (pickerViewoption.tag==1)
        {
            return [brands count];
        }
        else if (genderPickerView.tag==2)
        {
            return [gender count];
        }
        else if (activityPickerView.tag==3)
        {
            return [activity count];
        }


        return 0;
    }




    - (IBAction)action:(id)sender; {
          if (isCheckedpickerView==FALSE)
        {
            pickerViewoption.hidden=NO;
            isCheckedpickerView=TRUE;

        }
        else
        {
            isCheckedpickerView=FALSE;
            pickerViewoption.hidden=YES;
         }

    }




    - (IBAction)genderAction:(id)sender {


        if (isCheckedpickerView==FALSE)
        {
             genderPickerView.hidden=NO;
             isCheckedpickerView=TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            isCheckedpickerView=FALSE;
            genderPickerView.hidden=YES;

        }


         }

    -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];

        return YES;
    }



    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @end
```

Comment: Side note - why would you add each picker as a subview over and over again each time a picker view's title is requested? That's just silly.

Comment: Side note 2: If you use IB to create the picker views and assign them to the outlets, why do you also create the picker views in code (replacing the ones created in IB)?

Comment: @rmaddy yes right, it is allocated the picker which is already allocated in IB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you are checking wrong condition in delegate methods, replace following 3 methods **in .m file** :

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

      NSString *string;

      if (pickerView.tag==1) {
           [tabView1 addSubview:pickerViewoption];
           string=[self.brands objectAtIndex:row];
                }

      else if (pickerView.tag==2){
            [tabView1 addSubview:genderPickerView];
            string=[self.gender objectAtIndex:row];
               }

      else if (pickerView.tag==3){
            [tabView1 addSubview:activityPickerView];
            string=[self.activity objectAtIndex:row];
               }

      else  {
            [tabView1 addSubview:genderPickerView];
            string=[self.gender objectAtIndex:row];
                      }

      return string;

}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
               inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

   if (thePickerView.tag==1){
          BrandLabelfield.text=@"";
          BrandLabelfield.text=[brands objectAtIndex:row];
          BrandLabelfield.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
          pickerViewoption.hidden=YES;
        }
    else if (thePickerView.tag==2){
          GenderLabelfield.text=@"";
          GenderLabelfield.text=[gender objectAtIndex:row];
          GenderLabelfield.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        }

    else if (thePickerView.tag==3){
          ActivityLabelfield.text=@"";
          ActivityLabelfield.text=[activity objectAtIndex:row];
          ActivityLabelfield.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        }

}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
        numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

            if (pickerView.tag==1)
            {
                return [brands count];
            }
            else if (pickerView.tag==2)
            {
                return [gender count];
            }
            else if (pickerView.tag==3)
            {
                return [activity count];
            }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component { } what i need to change

Comment: check the if else condition in that method

Comment: what is pickerView  here . in may case . pickerview name (first pickerview , secondpickerview ,etc) @iPhone Dev

Comment: pickerView is a local method object.

Comment: i did not get what are you telling

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54694/discussion-between-square-and-iphone-dev).